# Convert the date "Tue Aug 18 2020 12:30:44 GMT+0530" to "Tue Aug 18 2020 12:30:44 GMT+05:30"

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, momentjs

I am getting the current date and time using `new Date()` and added as a text content for div tag.

**Working snippet:**

```js
const currentDateTime = new Date();
document.getElementById('demo').textContent = currentDateTime;
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

It is working fine, but I am in the need to change the format of the date.

**From:**

```
Tue Aug 18 2020 12:30:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**To:**

```
Tue Aug 18 2020 12:30:44 GMT+05:30 (India Standard Time)
```

Colon (**:**) needs to be added for the gmt like

> `GMT+05:30`

In real application I am using moment js and getting the current date and time using `moment()`. So moment js way of solution would also help me.

Comment: Try using [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) and modify as per your need.

Comment: `new Date().toString().replace(/(\d\d)( \(.*$)/, ':$1$2');` No library, no timezone issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the "Z" format token to indicate the UTC offset in a +-HH:mm format using moment.js. We can also include the GMT literal in the format string as [GMT]. It's documented [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

I'm using moment.tz here to force the timezone to +5:30, but assuming its your local time, you'll just do moment() instead!

For example:

```js
let m = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata");
console.log(m.format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the index of `:` is always the same in your case, you can use the following method:

```js
const text = 'Tue Aug 18 2020 12:30:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
let textArr = text.split('')
textArr.splice(31, 0, ":")
const newText = textArr.join('')
```

Comment: Or `text.replace(/([+\-])(\d\d)(\d\d)/, '$1$2:$3')`. :-)